# Restore DB to older version

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

We have a scenario where we need to restore a SQL Server 2012 backup to a SQL Server 2016 environment, drop a few files to make more room, take a backup, and restore it back to another SQL Server 2012 environment again. Using the "GENERATE SCRIPTS" task is not an option as the DB is extremely large and complicated. Basically, is there a way to retain the old compatibility mode without automatically upgrading it, while restoring, using, and backing up an older version database in a newer version server?

None of the process above is negotiable or will be elaborated upon, these are the constraints I have to work with. Thanks for any help!

Comment: You cannot copy a database from a 'higher' version (2016) of Sql Server to a 'lower' version of Sql Server (2012). That's called 'downgrading' and it not supported.

Comment: >>>is there a way to retain the old compatibility mode without automatically upgrading it, while restoring<<< No, there is no such a "mode". Onced attacched/restored, the database is upgrading and the process is irreversible

Comment: Yeah this is the conclusion I came to as well. Thanks both!

Comment: I don't mind if it's tagged as a duplicate, but it is a different question. The reason I posed this question is because there's a big difference between taking an original new version DB and then downgrading that (as is the case in the post you linked to), compared to my situation where you are literally working with an older version DB all the time, but have to run it through a newer version server between backups. However, as the end result seems to be the same, ie. it doesn't work, then I suppose it doesn't matter.